# WiX Burn uninstall will not uninstall .EXE files

Tags: wix, dependencies, burn, uninstallation

I have multiple Exe dependencies installed from my WiX Burn bootstrap project including MongoDB, RabbitMQ and some dependencies. Does anyone know why uninstalling the app will uninstall the main application but it leaves these dependencies, and how to fix it so it will uninstall all of them?

Comment: Have you looked at the log file? What have you tried? There are a few hits on the web for general dependency uninstaller issues with WiX. So you should tell us how your problem is different from those ones.

Comment: Ate they dependencies of other bootstrappers? Are they marked permanent?

Comment: If these dependencies are referenced in Files.wxs, then wix will remove them upon uninstallation, unless marked permanent. 
The more common case is to reference the dependencies as external MSIs in your bundle. That way you can also define permanent configuration to keep these dependencies in the target machine upon uninstall, or otherwise remove them.
Could you elaborate upon the way in which you reference these dependencies?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, my code example did not upload so I'll try to explain this a better.  I got the answer about the MSI installs but the EXE files will not uninstall.  for example, the RabbitMQ is loaded as a dependency inside of a burn project using the ExePackage property. By the way, how can I add a code example to this message?

Comment: Please add your ExePackage definitions for these additional exe installs. Likely you are missing a correct DetectCondition. You can also take a look at the detect log lines from an uninstall of your bundle to see if it detects the ExePackages as installed or Absent

Comment: You should be able to just copy paste your code into the edit window. Make sure **all your code is indented by an additional 4 spaces** so that it gets parsed as a code block by stack overflow.